# Build a table with php and mySqli

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

i'm trying to do a table with php and mysqli and i want to see the results in the html. For some reason it is not working

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
        <?php
    require 'connect.php';
    $link->query("SELECT nome, id_utilizador FROM utilizador");

    echo "NSA INFORMATION";
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";
    echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>NAME</td>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["nome"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["id_utilizador"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

 ?>
```

Comment: `echo "</table>"` after the `while` loop. Now html is not valid as `table` has now required closing tag.

Comment: Guessing, since you've provided no useful details about HOW this isn't working, but you're mixing two different DB access styles. `$link` is an object, and nowhere do you set/create `$query`.

Comment: you forgot to add `</tr>` at your header `echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>NAME</td></tr>";` that's why your table doesn't work.

Comment: `$query = $link->query(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "</table>";` after the `while` loop. In your code outputted html is not valid as `table` element has no required closing tag. You also forgot the closing tag for `tr` before the `while` loop and close the opening tag for `table`.

Comment: See comments in OP. There's more than just `</table>` missing